# How to add an event listener only to a parent element

Tags: html, reactjs, events

I am developing an e-shop card with React. I added onMouseOver and onMouseOut event listeners to the parent div. React propagates these event listeners to all its children, so an event is triggered every time the cursor enters or leaves a child element. I want a different behaviour - the event should only be triggered when the cursor enters or leaves the parent component, not its children.

I tried to find the solution on the internet, but suprisingly only stopPropagation method was supposed.

React gurus, please advise the solution.

This is my component:

```
function GoodCardMod(props) {

    ...

    const handleMouseOverGoodCard = (event) => {
        console.log('Over');
    };
    const handleMouseOutGoodCard = (event) => {
        console.log('Out');
    };


    return (
        <div 
            className='good-card-container component-container'
            onMouseOver={handleMouseOverGoodCard}
            onMouseOut={handleMouseOutGoodCard}
        >
            <img 
                src={good.good_image} 
                alt={good.name} 
                className='good-card-image'>
            </img>
            <span className='good-card-title'>
                {good.name}
            </span>
            <span className='good-card-price'>
                {good.current_price} грн
            </span>
            <Button 
                size='small' 
                onClick={isInCart[0] ? ()=> {} : () => cartDispatcher(addToCartAction(cartGood))}
                variant="contained"
                className='good-card-button'
                color={isInCart[0] ? 'success' : 'primary'}
            >
                {isInCart[0] ? 'Вже у кошику' : 'У кошик'}
            </Button>
            <CharachteristicsList characteristics={good.good_characteristics} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Does `event.stopPropagation()` work?

Comment: Yes, it does, but the parent event is not triggered at all. In other words nothing happens on entering/leaving the Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking `event.currentTarget === event.target` in the `onMouseEnter` of your parent component. This would replace `onMouseOver` in your current code.

```
    const mouseIn = (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget === event.target) {
          console.log('In');
       }
    };
    const mouseOut = (event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget === event.target) {
          console.log('Out');
       }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Sid, I've just tried your suggestion. It does not work in the desired way either. I've been searching the internet for the solution for hours and I`ve come to the conclusion that the behaviour that I want is not achievable. But your code  (event.currentTarget === event.target) will work better then mine for another task :)